# I have declared primary using PartitionKey annotation but still getting Entity Order does not declare a primary key

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have the following POJO:

```
@Entity
public class Order {    
    
    @Column(name = "id")
    @PartitionKey
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private String customerId;

    @Column(name = "loyalty_id")
    private String loyaltyId;

    @Column(name = "customer_email")
    private String customerEmail;

    public Order() {

    }
    public String getId() {
       return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    ... getters and setters
}
```

Getting the exception at the following code:

```
            CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().build();
            OrderMapper mapper = new OrderMapperBuilder(session).build();
            orderDao = mapper.orderDao(CqlIdentifier.fromCql(connectionManager.getSession().getLoggedKeyspace()));
```

The definition of connectionManager is here: https://pastebin.com/b3GKJuV6

The exception is as:

```
    Entity Order does not declare a primary key
    com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.MapperException: Entity Order does not declare a primary key
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.MapperException.copy(MapperException.java:44)
        at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
    ...
```

I am implementing by following the documentation here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.2/manual/mapper/ . What could be the possible cause of this?

EDIT:- Adding the schema definition:

```
    CREATE TABLE order_keyspace.order (
        id text PRIMARY KEY,
        customer_email text,
        customer_id text,
        loyalty_id text
    ) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
        AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
        AND comment = ''
        AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
        AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
        AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
        AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
        AND default_time_to_live = 0
        AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
        AND max_index_interval = 2048
        AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
        AND min_index_interval = 128
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
        AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: Is your keyspace also called order? mapper.orderDao(CqlIdentifier.fromCql("order")); seems to indicate it is, but just want to double check.

Comment: @Andrew yes it is that only. I have also tried using the loggedKeySpace from session.

Comment: @Andrew I have a class called ConnectionManager as follows: https://pastebin.com/b3GKJuV6 and another class called OrderRepositoryService where the connection manager is used as : https://pastebin.com/8gnWr149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full Edit :

There are a few things going on here which confuses me, and the only way I could reproduce the error was to break the getter/setter which doesn't appear to be wrong on your code, but there is some copy/paste conversions that are happening. What I can so far see as follows:

- The use of @Column(name = "id") - which is not an annotation from com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations. @CqlName should be used.
- The use of a reserved keyword for a table - the term 'order' is a reserved keyword, I am pretty sure this results in considerable confusion within the code - although I got a different error when I attempted to use the keyword as a table name with the mapper. I think you should name this table to something else and avoid the keyword.

Annotation Link:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.2/manual/mapper/entities/ contains the rules / annotations available and you can see the use of @CqlName there to inform the mapper of the Cassandra column name if it differs from the naming convention.

I belive you were on the 4.2 driver in an earlier question - but if updated to 4.7 (recommended) then this is the link : https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.7/manual/mapper/entities/ )

The following code worked correctly:

Cql:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_orders (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_email text,
    customer_id text,
    loyalty_id text
);

insert into customer_orders (id, customer_email, customer_id, loyalty_id) values ('a','a@b.c.com', '1234', '5678');
```

Pojo:

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.CqlName;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Entity;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.PartitionKey;

@Entity
public class CustomerOrders {
    @CqlName("id")
    @PartitionKey
    private String id;

    @CqlName("customer_id")
    private String customerId;

    @CqlName("loyalty_id")
    private String loyaltyId;

    @CqlName("customer_email")
    private String customerEmail;

    public CustomerOrders() {

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getLoyaltyId() {
        return loyaltyId;
    }

    public void setLoyaltyId(String loyaltyId) {
        this.loyaltyId = loyaltyId;
    }

    public String getCustomerEmail() {
        return customerEmail;
    }

    public void setCustomerEmail(String customerEmail) {
        this.customerEmail = customerEmail;
    }
}
```

DaoMapper:

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlIdentifier;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.*;

@Mapper
public interface DaoMapper {

    @DaoFactory
    OrderDao orderDao(@DaoKeyspace CqlIdentifier keyspace);
}
```

OrderDao:

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Dao;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Delete;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Insert;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Select;

@Dao
public interface OrderDao {

    @Select
    CustomerOrders findById(String id);

    @Insert
    void save(CustomerOrders order);

    @Delete
    void delete(CustomerOrders order);
}
```

I then created a simple test snippet:

```
 @Test
    void GetRecordViaOrderDao() {
        try (CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().build()) {

            DaoMapper daoMapper = new DaoMapperBuilder(session).build();
            OrderDao orderDao = daoMapper.orderDao(CqlIdentifier.fromCql("killrvideo"));
            CustomerOrders order = orderDao.findById("a");
            System.out.println(order.getCustomerEmail());
        }
    }
```

killrvideo keyspace in this instance because I am hitting an Astra DB and thats the keyspace I have there currently.

```
Result: a@b.c.com
```

Driver version 4.7.2 was specified in my pom.xml

Comment: I have tried removing `@Column` annotation. Didn't help. Also, the primary key column name is intended to be used as `id` itself so I didn't thing it would be necessary to use `@CqlName` annotation there.

Comment: Can you include the Schema definition of the Order table from Cassandra in the question please.

Comment: hey @Andrew I have updated the question with the schema definition also.

Comment: I have added the code for my getter/setter for primary key

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the code you gave to try reproduce -    CREATE TABLE order_keyspace.order - you had said the keyspace was called order, not order_keyspace, is that just a modification you made when pasting?

Comment: yes I modified it while pasting earlier. order_keyspace is the real name

Comment: Ok, order is also a reserved keyword, I would of expected it in double quotes.

Comment: Actually, the issue is that I had created a similar project with 2 POJOs User and Address where Address was UDT within User and had a similar setup as this, except if you noticed my ConnectionManager here has to be configured explicitly while in the other project which actually ran fine had all the configurations read from a `.properties` file in a static block wherein it also initialized the DaoMapper for User. I tried replicating that also, still no luck. So this is what's puzzling me so much, similar projects, one is working while the other is not.

Comment: Fully edited - included code that works against that table definition, and correctly returned the email.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew thanks for that, I was using the wrong import for `@PartitionKey`. The correct one is this `import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.PartitionKey;` which you have mentioned.